# Excel - Handling Checkbox name changes

Tags: c#, excel, checkbox

I am coding against an Excel document. I get many different instances of this Excel document. Basically, it is the same layout but different data within it. Occasionally, I will run into a case where a few Checkbox names are changed. No one is changing them manually. It is almost like Excel changes them? They will go from 'Check Box 10' to the next available number for a Checkbox.

What causes these names to change? It is a headache to constantly change my code to handle a different checkbox name. Also, is there a different way to get the checkbox value other than finding it by name?

Comment: you could run all shapes and filter for check boxes. there you can go for the TopLeftCell to know where it is. If the layout stays the same, then the names doesnt matter anymore

Comment: What if there are multiple checkboxes I parse?

Comment: The Checkbox name increments in case another Checkbox is inserted in addition to the ones already present. But then, are the initial set of Checkboxes inserted by you ?

Comment: I didnt create the document. I went off the first instance of the document with data in it. I coded against the checkbox names. Now, sometimes, I get a new instance of the document with data in it but a checkbox name is given a new id number. I am trying to find out what is causing this and if there is a way I can work around it.

Comment: How about adding some custom text to the check boxes in `AlternativeText` property when you deal with the first instance. That way you can later identify by that property ?

Comment: I like the idea. I will ask the people in charge of the document to see if we are able to try that.